# Перевести ориентацию экрана в Landscape только для одного ViewController

Tags: swift3

Пересмотрел все ответы на англоязычном языке, но ничего подходящего не нашел к сожалению. По дефолту в настройках проекта включен только `Portrait`режим. Нужно не главные экран, а другой один экран разрешить доступ к вертикальному просмотру. Т.е он должен поддерживать и `Landscape` режим и `Portrait` режим. Обязательно swift 3. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В `Info.plist` выставьте портретную и альбомную ориентацию, а в нужных контроллерах заблокируйте поворот:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    get {
        return .portrait
    }
}
```

---

Если в `Info.plist` выставить только портретную, а в контроллере прописать, к примеру, все ориентации

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    get {
        return .all
    }
}
```

то все-равно поворачиваться не будет.

Comment: прописал в info.plist 4 ориентации (top, left right, bottom). Затем поставил override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask { get {return .portrait}} в NavigationController (на другие ставил без навконтролера не работает). И все экраны которые идут от него по иерархии у всех portrait. А мне надо из этой иерархии у последнего экрана  установить  .all.  Пока не получается.

Comment: Может последнему экрану отдельно NavigationController создать ? чтоб наверняка ? и переход программно прописать ?